# Creating a "generated" number from an NSString

Tags: ios, nsstring

I'm trying to find a way that I can turn any string into a generated, deterministic number.

That is...

1. Each time that the same string is used it will create the same
   number.
2. Different strings will (probably) create different numbers.

For instance, you could add the letter indices in the alphabet for each letter in the string.

Of course, this wouldn't work for strings in languages that don't use the same alphabet.

There must be a better way to get something like that to work though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSObject has a method called "hash" that will do this for you: [NSObject hash](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/hash)

in ObjectiveC:

```
NSUInteger value = myString.hash;
```

in Swift:

```
let value = myString.hash
```

Comment: Cool thanks. Tried this but it didn't work. Tried again and now it works. LOL! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`NSString.hash`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSString/hash), or yes, other languages' characters are also represented by numbers: if you don't mind the size, you can contact them. [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) also creates (hexadecimal) numbers from strings.

Comment: OK weird, could have sworn I'd tried that but got an error on it. Tried now and it works. LOL! Thanks

Comment: I accepted the other answer as it included the code also. Both answers were equally correct. Thanks